# Insert a pdf file in a QTextDocument and then printing the result

Tags: qt, pdf

I was wondering if the following is possible. I want to write an report writing tool. So the idea is that some one fills the blanks, adds the information in some sort of simple text editor, they press a button and presto! A report with proper headings and a uniform standard is generated. However there is one problem that I need to solve before I dive into this. The tool must allow the inclusion of other pdf files, and from what I've been reading this is not possible. Here is an Example of what I want:

Some rich text.

Annex I

datasheet.pdf

Some more reach text.

What I want is for the datasheet.pdf to be inserted as is a that approximately that point in the final pdf file (so page numbering and so on can be consistent). Is this possible? If so any idea how?

Thanks for any answers!

Comment: Qt doesn't provide support for PDF files, you will have to rely on a third party library to get rich text out of a PDF. You can save/print as PDF but you cannot open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ddriver mentioned, Qt doesn't directly support opening PDF files for editing purposes.  [Here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Handling_PDF) is a useful link which discusses various available options for working with PDFs in Qt.

Comment: I imagined. Thank you for the link!